# How to pass 'event' parameter through a knockout callback function in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, knockout.js

So I have a main function which should validate if we have permissions to execute the callback function. It works fine on chrome and opera, but I can't figure out how to get the event parameter in Firefox.

[Here's a working example (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/agjt6/304/), trying to execute it on firefox will return:

> ReferenceError: event is not defined

HTML:

```
<button data-bind="click: validation.bind($data,true,callback,'callback_param1_because_of_reasons',event)" id="test">
test
</button>
```

JS:

```
    var ViewModel = function () {

      this.validation = function(param1, callback){
        var do_validations = param1;

        if(do_validations){
            var parameters_a = [];
            $.each(arguments,function(key,val){
                if(typeof val != "undefined"){
                    parameters_a.push(val);
                }
            });

            //Executa el cb
            parameters_a.splice(0,2);
            callback.apply(this,parameters_a);
        }

        };

      this.callback = function(param1, event){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(event.target).hide();
        alert(param1+" ...everything's gonna be alright");
      };
    }

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Sorry for the mess with the tabulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knockouts `click` or other `event` bindings will always pass two parameters:

1. The current `$data` of the binding context, and
2. The raw `event`

Bind works by setting the `this` context (first argument), and appending any other argument passed. Knockout will respect these bound arguments and add the data and event at the end.

This means that your listener function's signature should include `data` and `event` at the end. It's thereby fixed how many arguments you need to `bind`, or you need to use an `array` if you want a varying amount.

Example:

```js
var vm = {
  myListener: function(arg1, arg2, data, event) {
    console.log("Arg 1:", arg1);
    console.log("Arg 2:", arg1);
    console.log("vm:", data);
    console.log("event:", event.type);
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<button data-bind="click: myListener.bind(null, 'arg1', 'arg2')">click</button>
```

Comment: Ok, got it working on the example http://jsfiddle.net/agjt6/307/ Thank you!